Unable to change b-bone size in Edit mode and use Ctrl-Alt-S hotkey (Blender 4.1)
I'm using Blender 4.1 to change the B-bone size. But I am only able to change the bone size up and down the Z-axis.
If my original filename is "unableToChangeBoneSize1.blend", using the Ctrl-Alt-S hotkey got me to save my file as "unableToChangeBoneSize2.blend" instead.
Is there anything I missed?

As Xana says, the shortcut has changed ;)

Resolved the problem.
From edit mode, select the b-bone you wish to change the size of, go to "Armature > Transform > Scale B-Bone" and move your mouse accordingly to change the size.
Thanks.
